Having invalid_client error while generating "access_token" for Epic EMR with hyperspace
I have a code that redirects users to the launch page and I'm getting the Authorization Code for an Access Token.
Epic document mentioned 2 methods for getting the access token.

If You Are Not Using a Client Secret - this code is working successfully
but as I want a refresh token too that's why I have to use 2nd method
on the second method document mentioned passing Authorization with a header
I'm following the same method but still getting the client_invalid

I think the error happened because of the wrong Authorization but as per the document i pass the every parameters and data
let data = {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
  };

  const body = encode(data);
  const authHeader = 'Basic ' + base64url.encode(`${clientId}:${encodeURIComponent(clientSecret)}`);

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": authHeader,
    },
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token",
      body,
      config
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(
      "Token Exchange Request Error:",
      error.response ? error.response.data : error.message
    );
    throw error;
  }


When did you generate the client secret for your app? It can take up to 12 hours for changes to your app to sync, so it could be that enough time hasn't passed.

yeah it's been 2 days since I created a client secret and I'm still getting the same error
